# Show page when accessed directly via URL React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have built an app that doesnt have a server. It just pulls data from a couple of endpoints.
When someone tries to access a page that isnt the root URL they receive a `Page not found` message.
I havent managed to find a solution to this that doesnt involve writing a server. Im really hoping that I can avoid that because the app really is too simple to need it.

When I navigate to `http://url.com/nextPage` it returns a `Page not found`, but if I navigate there from the root `http://url.com/` I dont have any issues.

I have not pushed an app to production before so this was an unexpected issue, but it is also important to how the app works that users are able to access a page directly via the URL.

My `App.tsx` file. Both pages are just straight forward React.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route
        path='/'
        exact
        component={HomePage}
      />
      <Route
        path='/nextPage'
        component={NextPage}
      />
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen??  Did you import any of these two components to your App??

Comment: When your browser opens `http://url.com/nextPage` the server should serve `index.html` but I think your server tries to serve a file 'nextPage' and that doesn't exist.

Comment: I think this can be handled through your hosting provider, you might not need a server to redirect after all. What hosting are you using for production?

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac Im using Netlify. I will look into it and see what I can do. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since now I know you are using Netlify as your hosting provider, there is a way to do it without having your own server. Netlify has lots of configuration, one of it being `redirects`.

You could try adding to your Netlify.toml the following:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

Or, you could create a `_redirects` file, with the following content:

`/* /index.html`

Take a look at this documentation: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/01/16/redirect-rules-for-all-how-to-configure-redirects-for-your-static-site/

Comment: I went with the `_redirects` file. A nice simple solution.